# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded (ParticlesJS function)

Tags: javascript

I've forked the Particles.js repo and only made a few changes to the code. I've never touched this part of the source code but I guess something I've changed elsewhere causes this problem.

The row that throws 'Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded' is the following row:

```
p1.x = position ? position.x : Math.random() * pJS.canvas.w;
```

in the function:

```
  pJS.fn.vendors.checkOverlap = function(p1, position){
    for(var i = 0; i < pJS.particles.array.length; i++){
      var p2 = pJS.particles.array[i];

      var dx = p1.x - p2.x,
          dy = p1.y - p2.y,
          dist = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);

      if(dist <= p1.radius + p2.radius){
        p1.x = position ? position.x : Math.random() * pJS.canvas.w;
        p1.y = position ? position.y : Math.random() * pJS.canvas.h;
        pJS.fn.vendors.checkOverlap(p1);
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: probably, better to post code which you changed?

Comment: pJS.fn.vendors.checkOverlap potentially calls itself (recursion). This could lead to stack issues, either by too large a dataset or bad case. Also, you are not passing in 'position' when checkOverlap is getting called - should it be getting passed in?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and suspect the reason is the size of the particles being too big and so when bounce is activated, they have no where else to go...

Comment: This should be a comment, it doesn't answer the question.